# Using MSAL for Azure AD-B2C in AspNetCore?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Here is my problem, I create a brand new AspNetCore WebApplication in VS2017 RC.

Since I want to use Azure AD B2C to authenticate, I add the required NuGet packages:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
```

I then add all the code to configure authentication. In fact, I reproduced the app demoed in this Channel9 video: https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Ignite/Australia-2017/CLD336a

It works fine and I can authenticate as expected. Now I want to get an access_token in order to access my WebApi also secured using AAD-B2C. For this, I need to change the ResponseType to

```
ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken
```

and handle the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event. In order to do that, my understanding is that I have to add the Nuget Package `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`. But this library will not target the v2.0 endpoint that I need for AAD-B2C.

So I saw in another GitHub solution (https://github.com/dzimchuk/azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-core) that i could use the `Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` package.

Unfortunately, this package is not compatible with NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 and I get this error message when trying to add it to my project:

> One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (win-x64).
>
> Package Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 4.0.209160138-alpha
> is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) / win-x86.
> Package Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 4.0.209160138-alpha

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C does not currently support access tokens to a resource other than "self".  To get an access token for self, you just need to put your client/app id as the scope.  You can [post on User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c) to recommend this feature and check in on other user recommended features (this has been requested before).

In terms of your library confusion, you definitely want to stick with MSAL.  The ADAL experimental branch is not recommended and not actively being developed.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I am aware of the limitation and my scope is set to my client_id. But I still need to handle the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event in order to get the access_token to "self' don't I ?  If I do then I am stuck with the problem I described above.